# sorting a report in ruby with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a report which is generated from different models and I am displaying it as a table.Is there a way to sort this table.

This is my views code:

```
 %table
 %th Tester
 %th # Assigned Ics
 %th # Completed ICs
 %th % Completed
 %th Total Estd Effort

-@cycle.release.testers.each do |tester|
  %tr
    %td=link_to tester.name, cycle_ic_runs_path(@cycle, :tester_id => tester.id)
    %td=@cycle.ic_runs_by_tester(tester).count
    %td=@cycle.complete_ic_runs_by_tester(tester).count
    -percent=0
    -if @cycle.ic_runs_by_tester(tester).count >0 && @cycle.complete_ic_runs_by_tester(tester).count >0
      -percent=(@cycle.complete_ic_runs_by_tester(tester).count/@cycle.ic_runs_by_tester(tester).count)*100
    %td=percent
    %td=total_estd_effort_by_tester(@cycle,tester)
```

Here I want to apply sort to tester's name and Assigned Ic's and Completed ICs.
Please help me out with the jquery and the necessary ruby coding.

Comment: By which field do you want to sort? By tester? By count? By total estimate effort by tester? How have you tried to implement this? How did it not work?

Comment: Why not sort it in ruby code? Do you need there interaction, so the user clicks on the table header to sort it?

Comment: Hi arnold, I want to apply sort on all the 3 columns. In the asiicasts example that i see, sorting is based on the records that are retrieved from the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to implement sorting on tables, is to use Javascript on the client side.
Here's an overview of some jQuery plugins for this purpose:

http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-great-jquery-plugins-for-better-table-manipulation/

Personaly I'd recomend [DataTables.js](http://datatables.net/) (which can also handle pagination for you).
The simplest way to use this to make HTML tables sortable, is to just call `$('#my_table').dataTable();`

There are of course also [non-jQuery libs](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/) for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend Tablesorter 2.0 http://tablesorter.com/docs/